# Sqlite records and kivy buttons

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

Im trying to display some records from a database as buttons in kivy.

But when i click on them to get their text (row[3]) i always get the text from the last record. I want each button to have his own name.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.db')
c = conn.cursor()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM Table'):
    row = Button(text=row[3])
    button.bind(on_press=self.display)
    layout.add_widget(button)


def display(self,*args):
    print row.text
```

Comment: Maybe you've meant `button = Button(text=row[3])`...?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

`print self.text`

Also you can change button's text

```
display(self,*args):
print self.text
self.text='Clicked!'
```